# How do I exclusively disable some Apache modules directives to be used in .htaccess

Tags: apache-2.2, .htaccess

I'm a web hoster and a site owner.

As a hoster I wan't to disable the use of some module directives within the .htaccess for my customers sites.

Since some sites serves as a CDN, I want to disable for example AddHandler (and a few more) from mod_mime. So that even if php files are uploaded, they can't execute.

While directives like RewriteRule from mod_rewrite is still good to have.

To explain it in pseude code:

```
AllowOverride All -mod_mime -DocumentRoot -CustomLog -ErrorLog
```

The document
https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_mime.html#AddHandler
says the Context is .htaccess, could I limit the Context of this module directive?
I'm not afraid of patching or recompiling it.

How would I solve this?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer were right under my nose, literally.

You will need Apache 2.4 however

https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/core.html#allowoverridelist

Set

```
<Directory /var/www/vhosts>
    AllowOverride None
    AllowOverrideList RewriteEngine RewriteOptions RewriteBase RewriteCond RewriteRule
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```

Will allow only those directives specified within the AllowOverrideList.
All others will cause an internal server error.

Doing the same for whole modules is still missing though, but this is a good enough solution for me.

Thanks again SF

Answer (score 0):

`DocumentRoot`, `CustomLog` and `ErrorLog` are already not available in .htaccess, so that's not a problem.

As far as I know, there's no way to disable all of mod_mime specifically. You would have to disable all of FileInfo, which may not be what you want.

```
<Directory /var/www/vhosts>
   AllowOverride  All -FileInfo
   RemoveHandler .php
</Directory>
```

Comment: Ah, of course. I just used them for explaining. 

But patching and recompiling the module would be an option hopefully, was maybe an SO question after all. Thanks anyway :)